# Grunt concat and minification of css files

Tags: yeoman, gruntjs

I'm currently using the Yeoman generated Gruntfile and am looking to concat AND minify my CSS. The way I'm doing it for my JavaScript appears to be working fine however when i try and apply the same methods to my css files i just get them being concatenated together with no minification.

Here's what i'm doing in my index.html file:

```
    <!-- build:css styles/dist.bundle.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/loader.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/social.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" />
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

Note that if i remove the build block comments i do get a minified version but just in 3 separate files.

And in my Gruntfile config i have the following:

```
    cssmin: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/dist.bundle.css': [
                    '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'
                ]
            }
        }
    }
```

And my usemin config is just the default:

```
    useminPrepare: {
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
        options: {
            dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
    },
    usemin: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        options: {
            dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
        }
    }
```

Can anyone advise how i can achieve what i am looking todo? Or is this not possible with usemin & cssmin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

can you please pastebin your gruntfiles ? since usemin does NOT concat/minify/uglify by itself, but rather tell the tasks that will wich files to use, maybe you are not asking grunt to minify the files after it is concatenated

Comment: no it don't use min is just here to replace IN THE HTML the ref to multiple files by the one you gave to usemin then fire the concat / css min, so you need to put in your cssmin section a part where you min your dest file as well

Comment: but doesnt that mean i have to run this task after the usemin task? Which also means that if i run the 'rev' task i wont know the file name?

Comment: Wow! I missed that usemin doesn't actually concat or min. Thanks for making that clear :)